# Does a set of a certain size definitely contain $a,b,c$ such that $a+b=c$?

Tags: pigeonhole-principle, arithmetic-progressions

Suppose we are given a set $S \subset \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ with $|S|>n/2$. Is it true that $S$ contains some $a,b,c$ st. $a+b=c$?

A proof I saw does the following -

Consider the set $P =\{\max(S)-a:a\in S\}$. Clearly $|P| = |S| > n/2$. Therefore by pigeonhole there exists an $x\in P$ that is also in $S$. So $x=\max(S)-a'$ for some $a'$ in $S \implies \exists x,a'\in S : x+a'= \max(S)$.

This doesn't seem watertight, as the set $P$ contains a $0$, and therefore is not entirely contained in $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ so pigeonhole may not apply.

Is the original statement true? How do we prove it?

EDIT: What if $S\subset \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ and $|S|>n/2+1$

Comment: $n=3$, $S=\{1,3\}$ is a counterexample.

Comment: if S contains just two more than half of n, the 0 doesn't matter at all.

Comment: In fact all odd elements of any set with $n$ odd is a counterexample.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Ahh I see

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Ohh okay! Makes sense.

Comment: Why do you refer to this as a $3-$ term arithmetic progression?  If $r,s,t$ is an arithmetic progression, we do have $r+t=2s$, but that's different than what you wrote.

Comment: @lulu Because the question was formulated that way

Comment: Well, it isn't a three term arithmetic progression so it is very misleading to refer to it that way.  Seems like an error somewhere down the line.

Comment: @lulu Why isn't it though?

Comment: A three term  arithmetic progression means a triple $a, a+d, a+2d$ for some $a, d$.  The gaps are a constant size ($d$ in this case).  We note that $a+(a+2d)=2a+2d=2(a+d)$.   Here, the natural counterexample to your claim (just taking the odd elements) is clearly an arithmetic progression (constant gap $2$).

Comment: @lulu Ohhh okay i get what you're saying. Im sorry. I mixed up two problems, the next one asks whether there is a solution to $a+b=2c$. Ill change the title!

Answer (score 1):

The proof works for the $n \mod 2 = 0$ case. For $n \mod 2 = 1$, it works when $|S|> \lceil n/2\rceil$